# Error on Trigger SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

Hi I'm having a problem while I'm creating a trigger on SQL Oracle.

My trigger is:

```
    create or replace trigger generatePassword
before insert on people
for each row
begin
    insert into people(nif,naame,date_birth,sex,adress,email,iban,password)
    values (:NEW.nif,:NEW.naame,:NEW.date_birth,:NEW.sex,:NEW.adress,:NEW.email,:NEW.iban,(select round(dbms_random.value(0000,9999)) from dual));
end;
/
```

The trigger was created successfully. Then, when I try to run the command:

```
insert into people (naame, date_birth, sex, adress, email, iban, nif, id) values ('Albert', '01-12-87', 'M', 'NY', 'albert@gmail.com', '000032134537512343231', '523456189', '70');
```

I get this error:

> ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
>   ORA-06512: at "UTF8.GENERATEPASSWORD", line 2 ORA-04088: error during
>   execution of trigger 'UTF8.GENERATEPASSWORD' ORA-06512: at
>   "UTF8.GENERATEPASSWORD", line 2 ORA-04088: error during execution of
>   trigger 'UTF8.GENERATEPASSWORD' ORA-06512: at "UTF8.GENERATEPASSWORD",
>   line 2 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger
>   'UTF8.GENERATEPASSWORD' ORA-06512: at "UTF8.GENERATEPASSWORD", line 2
>   ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '

What is the problem here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PLSQL - Iinsert in trigger causing recursive loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851810/plsql-iinsert-in-trigger-causing-recursive-loop)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If a trigger on `people` tries to insert into `people`, you're going to get into an infinite loop (the initial insert fires the trigger which inserts a new row which fires the trigger again which inserts a new row which fires the trigger again...).  If you are just trying to change the `password` value from the initial insert, you'd just want `:new.password := round(dbms_random.value(0000,9999);`.

Comment: Justin, do you mean like this:
`create or replace trigger generatePassword
before insert on people
for each row
begin
:NEW.password = (select round(dbms_random.value(0000,9999)) from dual;
    insert into people(nif,naame,date_birth,sex,adress,email,iban,password)
    values (:NEW.nif,:NEW.naame,:NEW.date_birth,:NEW.sex,:NEW.adress,:NEW.email,:NEW.iban,:NEW.password );
end;
/
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has already been pointed out by Justin, you're code generates an infinite loop because the trigger fires for each insert statement included the one inside the trigger.
A possible solution is this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER generatePassword
BEFORE INSERT ON people
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
:NEW.password := round(dbms_random.value(0000,9999);

END generatePassword;
/
```

Whenever the trigger fires, a password is generated and added to the original insert statement.